# Is all access based on Thread's?

Tags: multithreading, ejb

my question is about thread's,
I am studying ejb and I see that it has many thread access controls, and working with ejb I could realize or at least imagine that all the access from the "remote client" (my doubt is this, only ejb?) Is thread based?
  Or in the ejb control the accesses of the thread's, my doubt is can I say that all the access coming from the remote client are thread's or can I manipulate those accesses with the use of api Thread?

I do not know if I was very specific, if so, is this also true for JSP'S and Servlet? Or just in case the EJB's can see I'm a bit confused.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

One of the basic goals of EJBs, since the beginning, is to relieve programmers from the pains and dangers to deal with thread management. Thread management is the responsibility of the Containers and it's not allowed to developers to deal with them.
As you can see from the link below "creation and management of threads"  it's not allowed:

[EJB Restrictions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/restrictions-142267.html)